# Bitnami multisite change URL of secondary blog

Tags: multisite, urls

I have the bitnami version of multisite wordpress.

I have the primary website which is `mysite.com` and a secondary blog which is `blog.mysite.com`. I would like to change the secondary address to `mysite.com/blog`. When I change the URL through the "Network", the "/wp-admin" doesn't work anymore.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps an issue with the wp-config.php setup for Network - what value do you have for the constant 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL' ?

Comment: I have "true" for SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL `define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );`

Comment: @QStudio I've tried to set it to `false` without much success

Comment: I know there's also something to do with how the server is set up to handle wildcards... ...but that may only be for subdomain installs/DNS, I genuinely don't remember but don't think it applies here... ...so obvious question is when you set SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL to FALSE, do you delete the second site and start a new one?  I don't think changing that in the config will change existing sites.

Comment: I had to delete and create a new site...thanks!